# Is Django Allauth deprecating?

Tags: django, django-allauth

Django 2.1
Python 3.6

I have begun to implement djanog alllauth because I've heard a lot of good things about it, however I just saw on an issue page on github that it isn't being maintained anymore (look at the link and the second to last comment). However, if you go to the gitlab page you'll see that it has commits as of beginning of March 2019. I'm confused now.

Should I be worried about this? Is there an alternative authentication app that I should be using instead?

I'm using it for the login, logout, password change, email verification and possibly social authentication.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/468

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the project has very recent commits so it's at least in some way still maintained.

However, you might still want to be concerned with maintenance in a general sense. Any package you use might deprecate with little warning or heads up, though likelihood will vary. If you're not sure that you will need social authentication, maybe stock Django authentication will work?

NB: I've used django-allauth in projects that are still live and updated and this works great, but I prefer stock authentication for newer projects.

Comment: You "prefer stock authentication"? WDYM? Why would you prefer to roll your own auth views/classes if you can use a tested, open-source, 3rd party library?